# Detect Eclipse version from JUnit test running in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, junit

I'm running a series of system tests developed with `Java` and `JUnit` within `Eclipse`, using the `Eclipse` console as output. I'm planning to implementing better console output for some tests using some console characters, which are not supported before Eclipse Mars (https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=76936).

To ensure compatibility with colleagues running an older version of `Eclipse`, I would need to **detect the `Eclipse` version in the JUnit test programatically**. Is this possible and if yes, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can get it by Java properties:

```
System.getProperty("eclipse.buildId").
```

Comment: I accepted this answer based on a fair coss toin, as there were two simultaneous answers.

Comment: @simon: Next time look at timestamps (`2015-06-12 09:49:12Z` and  `2015-06-12 09:49:14Z`) instead of tossing coins. ;)

Comment: @Aleksandr M: oops, you're right - greg-449's answer was 2 seconds earlier. I did not know one can see the exact timestamp with mouseover, I just saw "one minute ago" for both replies.

Answer (score 3):

```
System.getProperty("eclipse.buildId");
```

will give you the Eclipse build id, which will be something like

```
4.4.2.M20150204-1700
```